# Injetar script dentro do Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Ola, eu tenho a seguinte classe javascript

```
class MinhaClasse {
    static list() {
        return fetch('/api/endPoint', {
            method: 'GET', 
            headers: {
                'Authorization': Auth.getBasic()
            }
        })
    } 
}
```

Quando dentro do web worker eu chamo `MinhaClasse` ela é indefinida! como eu posso injetá-la dentro do worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para importar a classe basta usar a funcao `self.importScripts`

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts

Exemplo:

```
self.importScripts('/minhaClasse.js')
```